# Troubles using glib through gtk in Go with gco

Tags: go, cgo

My understanding of C is quite poor.  I can read the code, but I have no idea how to include/build/make/configure anything.  This is probably why I do not manage to get the following Go code to compile.  This code my attempt at adapting https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk-getting-started.html to Go.

```
package main

// #cgo pkg-config: gtk+-3.0
// #include <gtk/gtk.h>
import "C"

func main() {
    C.gtk_init(nil, nil)
    window := C.gtk_window_new(C.GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    C.g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", C.G_CALLBACK(C.gtk_main_quit), nil)
    C.gtk_widget_show(window)
    C.gtk_main()
}
```

The offending line is `C.g_signal_connect(...)`.  The errors are:

```
1: error: 'G_CALLBACK' undeclared (first use in this function)
1: error: 'g_signal_connect' undeclared (first use in this function)
1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

If I remove the line, then the code works and the gtk windows opens.

I figured out that this `g_signal_connect` comes from `glib-object.h`, which is included in many header files of `gtk`.  I tried to include it myself:

```
// #cgo pkg-config: gtk+-3.0 glib-2.0
// #include <gtk/gtk.h>
// #include <glib-object.h>
```

but it did not solve anything.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you're trying to call are probably actually macros, which are not handled by cgo and are therefore undefined. Take a look at [go-gtk](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk), which provides proper bindings to GTK for Go.

Comment: Indeed, they are macros (if that's what #define means).  go-gtk seems to be for gtk2, I wouldn't mind 3.  I'll see how they make it work though.

Comment: I found this article explaining how to get rid of macros: http://noeffclue.blogspot.nl/2012/07/experimenting-with-cgo-part-4-c-macros.html .  This explains why the go-gtk repository has its own .h file.  Good to know when making go wrappers.